# Where do I find "AttachmentID" for downloading an IBM Watson AutoAI model?

Tags: ibm-watson

I've been trying to do the following request from
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/machine-learning#models-download-content but I can't seem to find the AttachmentID value. This is the response I get.

```
{
  "trace": "d2b37730ffde257c8axxxxxxxx",
  "errors": [{
    "code": "does_not_exist",
    "message": "ATTSV3025E: Unable to find attachment for catalogId 'ee1d018b-69f9-4b56-xxxxxxxxxx' assetId '61ac09b4-564e-xxxxxxxxxx' attachmentId '61ac09b4-564e-xxxxxxxxx'.",
    "target": {
      "type": "parameter",
      "name": "61ac09b4-564e-xxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }],
  "status_code": "404"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching the `attachment_id` from the metadata returned from the model content metadata list endpoint:

```
attachments
Always included*

The metadata related to the attachment.
attachment_id
Always included*
string

The content id for the attachment.

Example: fd45606f-8098-459c-8961-32b136123fgc
```

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/machine-learning?code=JavaScript#models-list-attachments